# Change textView according to date/time (Java, Eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to create a textView that will change according to date and time. For example, I want to create a textView that'll say "Today is >weekday<". The app will check the date/time on the phone and check which day it is. For example on 6th June 2013 it'll say "Today is thursday".

I'd appreciate any help, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes of course, check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

All you need to do is create a textview, then get the current day of the week from the Calendar library and set the text of the textview using that information.

To make it dynamic, you'll need to put this in onCreate() and possibly onResume() that way each time that application is created or restarted the content of the textview can be reset.

Comment: For the lazy: String s = Calendar.getInstance().getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.LONG, Locale.US);